# flutter sqflite version solving fail in web

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

Because sqflite <=0.11.0+1 requires SDK version <2.0.0 or >=2.0.0-dev <2.0.0 and sqflite >=0.11.0+2 <=0.11.0+3 depends on flutter any from sdk, sqflite <=0.11.0+3 requires flutter any from sdk.
And because sqflite >=0.11.0+4 <=0.11.0+4 requires the Flutter SDK and sqflite >=1.1.2 requires the Flutter SDK, every version of sqflite requires flutter any from sdk.
So, because flutter from sdk doesn't exist (the Flutter SDK is not available) and bottom_navbar depends on sqflite any, version solving failed.

```
name: bottom_navbar
description: An app built using Flutter for web

environment:
  # You must be using Flutter >=1.5.0 or Dart >=2.3.0
  sdk: '>=2.3.0 <3.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter_web: any
  flutter_web_ui: any
  http: ^0.12.0+2
  sqflite: ^1.1.2
  charts_common:
  #sqflite: ^1.1.2



dev_dependencies:
  build_runner: ^1.5.0
  build_web_compilers: ^2.1.0
  pedantic: ^1.7.0

dependency_overrides:
  flutter_web:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/flutter/flutter_web
      path: packages/flutter_web
  flutter_web_ui:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/flutter/flutter_web
      path: packages/flutter_web_ui
```

Comment: `sqflite` currently not supported on `flutter web` platform.

Answer (score 3):

Currently, sqflite does not support web. There is an open issue on their GitHub for adding support https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/issues/212

In the meantime, there are other SQL type libraries for Flutter web. One I have used is https://pub.dev/packages/moor_flutter. Which is very similar to sqflite

Comment: so can you tell me which dependencies you used for sql

Comment: I use moor_flutter

Comment: same as sqflite moor_flutter not working so is there any other dependencies??

Answer (score 0):

here is the answer : you need to use dependency_override to fix your problem.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/66531585/8940630