# Flutter theme version solving failed

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test, flutter-theme

I am trying to run a flutter theme code in visual studio code and facing this issue after running command (flutter run)

Because every version of flutter_test from sdk depends on vector_math 2.1.0-nullsafety.5 and fstore depends on vector_math 2.0.8, flutter_test from sdk is forbidden.
So, because fstore depends on flutter_test any from sdk, version solving failed.
Running "flutter pub get" in ecomputex...
pub get failed (1; So, because fstore depends on flutter_test any from sdk, version solving failed.)

Please help[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJl2X.png)

Comment: Try running without specifying the package versions and let pub to that for you, for example: ```vector_math:```

Comment: What flutter version are you on?

Comment: @ScottGodfrey i on the latest one Flutter 1.26.0-17.2.pre (developer version)

Comment: Then you have a version conflict with fstore.  Flutter depends on vector_math 2.1.0-nullsafety.5  fstore depends on vector_math 2.0.8.

Comment: You will have to switch to stable channel.  run flutter channel stable, flutter upgrade.

Comment: @ScottGodfrey i just did it a minute ago and still when i run "Pub get" i get the same error which i mentioned in my question

Comment: Can you post your pubspec.yaml?  Just the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

just add this line of code in your pubspec

```
dependency_overrides:
  vector_math: 2.1.0-nullsafety.5
```

this will override the dependency, and you can use whatever version you want. you might need to change it the version of the package.

my code example:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0
  file_picker: ^3.0.0
  hive: ^2.0.0
  hive_flutter: ^1.0.0

dependency_overrides:
  path_provider: 2.0.1
```